# Unit testing for GCP upload

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, mocking, pytest

I have the following method for which I need to write unit test, I am new to using pytest. I am uploading a file to a bucket on GCP using the google.cloud storage library in python.

```py
def upload_to_gcs(topic, upload_file_name, upload_file_location, gcs_bucket_name, gcp_key_json):
    try:
        client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(gcp_key_json)
        bucket = client.get_bucket(gcs_bucket_name)
        gcs_folder_loc = topic + '/' + upload_file_name
        bucket.blob(gcs_folder_loc).upload_from_filename(upload_file_location)
        _LOGGER.info("File %s has been uploaded to folder %s", upload_file_name, topic)
    except Exception as e:
        _LOGGER.exception("Caught unexpected exception while uploading file to GCS %s", e)
    finally:
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(upload_file_location):
                os.remove(upload_file_location)
        except OSError as e:
            _LOGGER.exception("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
```

I have the following but I am not sure how to test the upload, Any help is appreciated -

```py
def test_upload_to_gcs():
    mock_client = mock.create_autospec(storage.Client)
    mock_bucket = mock.create_autospec(storage.bucket.Bucket)
    mock_bucket.name = 'test_bucket'
    mock_client.get_bucket.return_value = mock_bucket
    mock_blob = mock.create_autospec(storage.blob.Blob)
    mock_blob.name = 'test_blob'
    mock_bucket.get_blob.return_value = mock_blob
```

Comment: What do you want to test? That `upload_from_filename` is called with the correct location?

Comment: DustinIngram: I want to write unit test, basically check if upload succeeds.

Comment: Usually a "unit test" does not reach out to external services, and just tests an individual unit of the source code. Testing whether the _actual_ upload exceeds is more of an integration test, or a test of a 3rd-party library (here, the `google-cloud-storage` package).

Comment: take a look at how the repository implements it --> https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/master/tests/unit to try to get a sense of how you should proceed

Comment: Check this out. https://ramonmedeiros.dev/2019/11/11/mocking-google-api-python.html

Comment: link leads to SSL error, valid one is https://blog.ramonmedeiros.dev/2019/11/11/mocking-google-api-python.html